# ReactJS Create component by recieve a json from server

Tags: reactjs

I have a question for correctly handling my situation on ReactJS (I'm starting with react).
So, in my case, I receive a Json object from the server containing the field's list available for the user.

So I created:

- ScreenView: the screen to display
- DynamicComponent :  the component use on the page (giving the Fields json).

in the DynamicComponent I have this as Render :

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Stack>
                    {this.props.Fields.map((field) => (
                    this.getField(field)))}
                </Stack>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

And then, getField() method creates the right component using a switch case based on UIType from json fields.

```
getField(element) {
        let field;
        let items = this.fetchItems(element.Items);
        switch (element.UIType) {
            case 0:
                field  = (<DropdownComponent label={element.Name} options={items}  id={element.id} />)
                break;
            case 1:
                field  = (<TextFieldSimple label={element.Name} type='text' name={element.Text} id={element.id} />)
                break;
            case 2:
                field  = (<TextArea label={element.Name} type='text' name={element.Text} id={element.id} />)
                break;
            case 3:
                field  = (<CheckBoxSimple label={element.Name} enable='yes' disable='no' id={element.id} />)
                break;
            default:
                field  = (<h2>{this.props.Text}</h2>)
                break;
            }
        return field;
    }
```

This works very well actually. 
But My problem is , for some fields I have to change the data of it in the function of another field. 
For example :

2 dropdowns :

- Category : created with some values
- SubCategory : created empty but must be updated by using the selected value from the Category dropdown.

this is an example with two dropdowns but depending on the user I could have 3 or 4 or 5 sub categories.

So, anyone have an idea of how to properly handle this? 
Thank you in advance for your help!
Ps: I didn't find the answer on internet (I don't really know what to look for...)

Comment: Do you have an example of the json you are getting back from the server?

Comment: There is a Fields main object and each field in it has Items (options of dropdown). But I find a solution to day ;) thank you for your answer